# Decoding Unknown String in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, rfid

I have an RFID scanner connected to my Raspberry Pi and I am trying to read the input through python.

I am reading the input through UART and currently have this as my base reading script:

```py
import serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.2)

print("Reading RFID Tags now!")

while True:
    rcv = port.readling()
    if len(rcv) > 10:
        print("Tag Detected: " + rcv)
```

Currently, this is the string that I am getting:

`070080BB5B67`
([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/xuBKc5nt) as StackOverflow is removing the special characters STX and ETX preceding and following those shown (*Start of TeXt* and *End*, resp.))

and it should be:

`0008436571`

I can't work out the method of decoding the value. I have been trying for several days now and have had no luck. If any of you could help that would be amazing.

(sorry if I missed anything out. I'm new to StackOverflow, writing questions that is)

Comment: you are getting three values.`07+0080BB5B+67`. `int( "0080BB5B",16)  = 0008436571`

Comment: What @venky is showing you is that the number is encoded in hexadecimal, i.e. base 16, not base 10, and that using the built-in `int()` function you can convert a hex string into a decimal number.